# Cannot validate firefox addon via web-ext

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm tring to sign a second version of my firefox extension using web-ext but i keep getting this error

```
Your add-on failed validation and could not be signed
FAIL

WebExtError: The extension could not be signed
    at _callee$ (C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\dist\webpack:\src\cmd\sign.js:134:15)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:21)
    at step (C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\dist\webpack:\node_modules\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:17:1)
    at C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\dist\webpack:\node_modules\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:28:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I don't understand why this is happening because the first time i tried to sign it it worked.
PS : i already wrote a new version in my manifest.json script
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: This is happening for me as well at the moment, manage to figure out the reason? seem like there is an error in the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above the line "Your add on failed...", do you get a line like this?:
Validation results: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/upload/....

I had the same error message, and following that link showed me a detailed analysis of why it failed. My error was that I had a file called Translator.js, but in the manifest it was listed as translator.js, notice the case. After renaming it, signing succeeded.

Answer (score -2):

if you are on windows try:

1. run cmd as administrator.
2. run sign command without using batch file